# Programmatically determine whether a branch is closed in a github project

Tags: github-api, octokit.net

I'm using octokit .net to work with enterprise repositories and I'm stuck filtering out closed branches.

I found a good open example: https://github.com/google/grr/branches
As you can see, "server-0.3-6" is closed "darrenbilby-patch-1" is merged, others are plain normal.

However, in https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/branches/ there's nothing that hints me in direction of checking whether a branch is closed/merged. I also failed to find examples for octokit.

How do I?

Answer (score 1):

There's no concept of a branch being closed, only the pull request that references that branch (which is what GitHub is displaying when it says the branch is "closed"). With a bit of fiddling you can find out if a branch is closed by looking for an associated pull request using the [list pull requests endpoint](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#list-pull-requests):

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/pulls
```

This will return an array of all pull requests, which you'll need to search through to find your branch name in the `['head']['ref']` section. Once you've found your matching pull request, you can check the `state` field to determine whether the "branch" has been closed.